# How to generate variable names in multiple insert statement?

Tags: stored-procedures, informix

I have 18 different pairs of table column names like:

```
name_1, surname_1, ... name_18, surname_18
```

I would like to generate 18 inserts with Informix SPL using something like:

```
define _counter Int;
define _name_1 varchar(20);
define _surname_1 varchar(20);
...
define _name_18 varchar(20);
define _surname varchar(20);

select  name_1,  surname_1, ...,  name_18,  surname_18
  into _name_1, _surname_1, ..., _name_18, _surname_18
  from names where name_id = 1;

for _counter = 1 to 18 loop 
  insert into person(name, surname) values (_name_+_counter,   _surname_+_counter);
end loop
```

If I try this I get syntax error. I am stuck with the terrible table design. Could you please advise if there is some similar/correct way of accomplishing this?

Comment: Note that if it 'worked', you would insert 18 different rows into the table, which is probably not what you want.  Your primary problem is that your table structure is hopelessly denormalized; life managing that table is going to be hell for ever.  For example, suppose you're looking for the records that reference John Smith; you'll need to write an 18-way OR condition: `WHERE (name_1 = 'John' AND surname_1 = 'Smith') OR (name_2 = 'John' AND surname_2 = 'Smith') OR …`, remembering to parenthesize the whole condition if there are other conditions to check.  So, your table schema is a disaster.

Comment: That said, in Informix 11.70 or 12.10, you can use Dynamic SQL: [`DECLARE`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_0658.htm), [`EXECUTE`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_0747.htm), etc — after building a string containing the SQL statement you want to execute, which isn't the one shown.  You'll need 36 parameters to your function, of course, to get the 18 name + surname pairs into the stored procedure; that's not pleasant either.  On the whole, redesign your system now and save headaches later.

Comment: Thank you for your input. I know that the design is not normalized and that it is everything you shouldn't do, but I am stuck with it. I can't change it. And yes, I would like to insert 18 different rows into the table :)

Comment: Put that information into the question — if there's a design you can't change, say so.  You'll garner some pity that way.  It would still be better to redesign things — nothing will make that any less true.  You need to provide a little more context and a little more of an MCVE ([MCVE]); how are you going to get the 18 (for an MCVE, 3 will be sufficient) name/surname pairs into the function.  Actually, you're going to be stuck writing out CALL sp_insert(15, name_15, surname_15) 18 times, because there aren't arrays for accessing the variables.  I think I somewhat misanalyzed your question.

Comment: I have updated my question.

Comment: 80% of my comments are running at a tangent.  The schema design is not good and it would be better to redesign it.  Informix SPL does not have support for arrays; what you want is an array.  It is going to be painful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the clearer outline of the question, I think you have to forgo the loop.  The best you can do is either 18 consecutive INSERT statements, or 18 calls to a stored procedure that executes one statement on each call.

Informix SPL does not have an array type, and you can only really use the loop with an array.  (I have seen loops with a CASE statement inside, one case for each iteration of the loop; they're seldom a good solution to a problem, and it isn't a sensible solution to this situation.)

I will repeat an observation from my previous comments: the design of a table with 18 pairs of columns is very sub-optimal.  However, it appears that you are trying to transfer data from this sub-optimal schema to a more sensible one with one row per name.

You could also consider using an 18-way UNION:

```
 INSERT INTO Person(Name, Surname)
     SELECT Name_1,  Surname_1  FROM Names -- WHERE name_id = 1
     UNION
     SELECT Name_2,  Surname_2  FROM Names -- …
     UNION …
     SELECT Name_18, Surname_18 FROM Names -- …
```

If the requirement is truly to have just the row where `name_id = 1`, you will need to add that criterion to each of the 18 SELECT clauses within the UNION SELECT statement.  There are other ways to add that filter condition, with different sets of trade-offs at the source code level (and perhaps different trade-offs in the optimizer).  Informix does not (yet) support CTEs (common table expressions, aka WITH clauses), which is a pity in this context.

Note that the code shown transfers all the data from Names into Person in a single SQL statement.  This might well be the closest to optimal process overall.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this is what you want (using informix 12.10FC6, not sure if it will work on previous versions):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE copy_paste_names (p_name_id INTEGER);

    DEFINE 
        l_query_string VARCHAR(255);  
    DEFINE
        iter INT;

    FOR iter IN (1 TO 18 STEP 1)
        LET l_query_string = 'INSERT INTO person (name, surname) SELECT name_' || iter || ', surname_' || iter || ' FROM names WHERE name_id = ' || p_name_id || ';';
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE l_query_string;
    END FOR;      

END PROCEDURE;
```

I assume that the `names` table will always have 18 pairs of columns named `name_?` and `surname_?`.

This procedure will just blindly try to copy each pair of `name_?`, `surname_?` columns from the `names` table into a new row in the `person` table. There isn't any kind of checks to see if there are actually values to be copied or if